# Could someone explain the "let" rule in squash?

Tags: rules, squash

According to [this site](http://www.englandsquashandracketball.com/play-squash-and-racketball/rules-of-play/squash) "(b) A Let shall be allowed: ... (iii) If an otherwise good return has been made, but the ball goes out on its first bounce. "

I'm not entirely sure what this means. Could someone describe this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

A let is basically a stroke that, due to some variety of circumstances, is counted as "void" and the point is completely replayed. The specific scenario you're referring to is when the first bounce of the ball in a rally lands outside of the area of play. It's not noted in the source you've provided, but it's also a let under the same rule if the ball manages to lodge itself in the court somehow, as opposed to bouncing naturally.

Comment: The text in question is unclear to me too. (Why not simply a stroke because the ball goes out?) I have browsed the Full Singles Rules (PDF) on the site in the question (redirected to englandsquash.com) but didn't find corresponding text. Can you improve on your answer?

Comment: Revisiting this answer... Does the ball going out in this case mean that it escapes the court area--possibly over a side or back wall where there is no barrier above the [high] out line? Before the ball has bounced twice.